# Ruby on Rails - How to represent "has_many" with enums?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

What's the best solution in a Rails 3.2 app to represent something like this:

```
appointment = Appointment.first
appointment.days_of_the_week = [Monday, Friday]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at the [Embedded Association](http://railscasts.com/episodes/189-embedded-association) RailsCast where Ryan Bates explains how to use bitmasks to avoid the use of another table, I think it could be a good idea in this case.

Comment: Is this still the best example using Rails 4.1 enum?

Comment: @grimmwerks probably not :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a Gem called [enumerate it](https://github.com/cassiomarques/enumerate_it) that does database enumeration on collections like this. So, I would use it to enumerate the different days of the week.

With the enumerated values, I would create this relation:

```
has_many :recurrent_occurrences
```

And I would put there two columns: the `appointment_id` and the number equivalent of the week_day.

If you're using a noSQL database like mongoDB, you can add the weekdays as an array or embedded on the record, so there is no need of the extra table.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the question is about how to combine specific enum value with has_many.  Assuming association model name is day and enum is week, following codes will select specific symbols when calling has_many association.

```
has_many :days, -> { where(day: [Day.week[:Monday],Day.week[:Friday]] ) }
```